# Android XML attributes

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

I've been learning Android for quite some time now, but still can't understand why these are equal in a resource file:

this

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
```

and this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
```

this

```
<item name="windowTitleSize">40dip</item>
```

and this:

```
<item name="android:windowTitleSize">40dip</item>
```

I can guess about the second one: "android" is the default package. No idea about the first one though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best explanation to this question could be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml).

If i understood this correctly it is basically two ways to refer to a resource, either in R class or XML. The values should be the same though.